# Are C++ strings and streams buffer overflow safe?

Tags: c++, overflow, buffer, iostream

If I use std::cin, std::cout and std::string, is there *any* possibility that someone will exploit the buffer overflow?

I ask this because I still see a lot of people that still use null-terminated strings instead of standard containers in C++.

Comment: A lot of people aren't coding in C++ -- they're using C++ to compile C code.

Comment: A lot of people believe they are coding in C++ when they are actually coding in a subset of C...

Comment: If you use them correctly, then no. But then, same can be said about anything.

Comment: You could say it is harder to use std::string incorrectly in comparison to C-String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. Of course, when you use C-style code/API's, there *is no difference*.

But using STL or C++ idioms doesn't guarantee that you're safe.

C++ gives you the choice, always. Contrast these two near-identical twins:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
std::string s(n, '*'); // create a data store of given size

std::vector<char> v(1000);
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), v.begin()); // NOT safe if n > 1000
```

safe variant:

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
if (n > MAX_LIMIT) 
    throw std::runtime_error("input too large");
std::string s(std::min(0, n), '*'); // note input sanitation

std::vector<char> v;
v.reserve(1000);
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(v)); // safe
```

Comment: `std::vector v();` That looks vexing.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: crawling into the corner. (I just hope you can see that happened due to editing the first snippet into the second...)

Comment: I see. This means if I use boundary checking on vectors and strings (at()), there is no way that someone will exploit buffer overflow in a different way. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure about the conclusions. If you use everything correctly, then the only possible errors should be allocation errors, which are signalled via exceptions. So you shouldn't need *any* sort of `if`s and buts. Your program is still a potential for a denial-of-service, though, say if it requests 20GB on a machine with ony 4GB physical RAM -- then the program is still entirely correct, but may force the OS to its knees. But that's outside the scope of "safe programming".

Comment: @milleniumbug: also, one point I tried to make is not so much the bounds checking, but rather to avoid the preallocation of fixed sizes. `std::back_inserter(v)` effectively calls `v.push_back(...)` repeatedly and thus the vector will grow as required.

Comment: std::back_inserter() sounds like a clever trick - I have to try that.

Comment: @milleniumbug: it's called an output iterator. Indeed it solves many of the 'problems' with buffer allocations, and writing generic functions that can return output just about anywhere, pre-allocated or not. [Read more on `Iterator Categories` (there are Input Iterators too...) on SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Iterators.html)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh. Silly typo. Thanks (feel free to edit next time :))

Comment: @sehe: Prefer to let you do it :P And I'm pretty sure you meant `n`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, I thought so too; but rereading the question for context, the ***point*** was to illustrate that it would be safe to just proceed with a `back_inserter` so I opted for analogous dimensioning as in the 'unsafe' (plain iterator) sample. (Took some reading. It was a while back)

Answer (score 14):

One of the big reasons you still see people using C-strings in C++ (besides not knowing about strings, or being stuck in a C mindset), is that `std::istream::getline` works with char pointers and not strings.  As do a huge number of other parts of the library.  Part of the reason for that was so that "you don't pay for what you don't use".  IE: people that just want to get a line of text shouldn't have to instantiate a `string` (thereby also having to pull in another template class) to do so.  You can use `std::getline` to get lines as strings if you want them, but that's not obvious.  So some people think they still need to use char buffers to get a line of text.

(Seems a lot of that is changed in C++11, and you can use `string`s in a lot of places where you had to pass a `char*` before.  Maybe that'll help a bit with the C-in-C++ problem.)

Standard strings and streams are designed to be overflow-resistant, and are all-around safer than a char pointer (at least when they're not *used* like a plain old array/pointer; blindly using `str`'s iterator without regard for `str.end()` is usually a bad idea, but `str.push_back()`, `str += "text"`, `str.at(x)`, and stream insertion/extraction operators are perfectly safe).  If you can use them, i highly recommend you do so.

Answer (score 12):

Still lot of people use null-terminated strings because they do not realize the convenience of using `std::string` and they are really writing procedural c++ not c++.

Most programmers migrating/migrated from c to c++ are the ones who still use null-terminated strings.

It is perfectly safe and you should use `std::string` in c++ wherever you can.

`std:string` actually protects you against buffer overflow(unlike c strings) by dynamically growing in size as the data added to it is increased.

An **[code sample](http://codepad.org/iIs2BxCr)**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str("std::String");
    for (int i=0; i<20; ++i)
    {
        cout << "capacity is " << str.capacity() << endl;
        str += " ,is Overrun safe string";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> capacity is 11
>   capacity is 35
>   capacity is 70
>   capacity is 140
>   capacity is 140
>   capacity is 140
>   capacity is 280
>   capacity is 280
>   capacity is 280
>   capacity is 280
>   capacity is 280
>   capacity is 280
>   capacity is 560
>   capacity is 560
>   capacity is 560
>   capacity is 560
>   capacity is 560
>   capacity is 560
>   capacity is 560
>   capacity is 560

Comment: "It is perfectly safe" - simply not true, see sehe's example. `std::string` is safe if you avoid accessing it out of bounds, but then again so are C-style strings. The difference is that you're less likely to need to worry about it with `string`, but the likelihood is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

C-strings may be faster, because std containers have to support some functionality that they support. So, nobody can point the best choice for all times.